# how to add onmouseover event javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onmouseover

In my html page i have drop-down list box.
I need to add `onmouseover` event dynamically via javascript for all option tag under my select tag. 
I'm using prototype.js
how to do this?

```
<select id="dash_key" name="dash_key">
    <option value="cginterval">Hosts and Applications</option>
    <option value="vsat">VSAT</option>
    <option value="LinkLayer">Link Layer Activity</option>
    <option value="protocols ">Protocols and Hosts</option>
    <option value="subnets">Hosts and Subnets</option>
    <option value="Netflow">Netflow Sources</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add some code, so we know what IDs, classes etc. we can use. Have you tried anything yourself, yet?

Comment: `<select id="dash_key" name="dash_key">
<option value="cginterval">Hosts and Applications</option>
<option value="vsat">VSAT</option>
<option value="LinkLayer">Link Layer Activity</option>
<option value="protocols ">Protocols and Hosts</option>
</select>`

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with separate events? I'm thinking if `onchange` on the select might be an alternative.

Comment: i need to add tooltip on mouseover event.

Comment: May `title="Tooltip text"` be enough? -- http://jsfiddle.net/D6zqc/

Comment: @smamatti: yeah enough. But I need some effects.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the observe method](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/).

```
Event.observe(element, "mouseover", handler)
```

… but note that browser support for mouseover events on option elements is probably very limited.

Comment: Why don't you try? And yes, I think so.